# Product images not showing on product page but loading fine everywhere including category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-images

The product images are not showing up on the product pages. All I did was - optimized few images on the media folder and replaced the current ones via ftp.

I then cleared the cache, re-indexed but the images are not showing up on the product pages. The image box is just blank. The images show up everywhere else. I went through all the suggestions I found online

- Increasing php memory limit
- Changing file permissions
- Indexes in htaccess
- Cleaning out cache and re-indexing
- Deleting .htaccess in media

But can't figure out the cause. Could anyone help me identify and fix the issue please?

Comment: before you optimize image , image will display in product view page?

Comment: and also you set base image thumbnail image for that product??

Comment: The images were displaying fine before. It's for all the product not just one product. All the base image, small image and thumbnail are set up

Answer (score 2):

If your website has multi store then double check your product's small, base and thumbnail images are assigned store wise or not.

Comment: I am afraid it's a single store website. Also, when I switch themes everything  works fine, the product images show up.